# docker stuck on pip install

Tags: django, docker, dockerfile

I have lots of headaches while trying docker, 
but this one is killing me
I am trying to install django on docker, but it got stuck on this line:

```
Successfully installed asgiref-3.2.7 django-3.0.6 pytz-2020.1 sqlparse-0.3.1
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
CMD chmod +x entry.s

# ENTRYPOINT ["./entry.sh"] # this will give me, ./entry.sh: Permission denied
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "./entry.sh"]
```

entry.sh:

```
echo entry point for django image
cd code
pip install -r requirements.txt

# for keep container running, I couldn't find any other way
touch app.log
tail -f app.log
```

docker run output:

```
entry point for django image
Collecting django
  Downloading Django-3.0.6-py3-none-any.whl (7.5 MB)
Collecting sqlparse>=0.2.2
  Downloading sqlparse-0.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (40 kB)
Collecting pytz
  Downloading pytz-2020.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (510 kB)
Collecting asgiref~=3.2
  Downloading asgiref-3.2.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
Installing collected packages: sqlparse, pytz, asgiref, django
Successfully installed asgiref-3.2.7 django-3.0.6 pytz-2020.1 sqlparse-0.3.1
--> stuck here
```

Answer (score 2):

In the `entry.sh`, as I can see, you have created an empty log file, and tailing it. Hence no response. Instead, run the django server:

```
# remove the log tailing file

python manage.py migrate
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Now, it is a good practice to install dependencies during the build process. In that way it will reduce time when you run the docker container. Also docker can cache those installations in layers, so it will reduce time to build. So I would recommend to create the `Dockerfile` like this:

```
FROM python:3.6
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8000
CMD python manage.py migrate;python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

No need to create an entry point for this implementation. If you want to check logs, then please check docker's [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/). Here is an example on how you can do that:

```
docker logs -f <container name>
```

Comment: but the touch and tail is after pip install, the problem is it won't pass the pip install.

Comment: No. It already completed pip installation. But again, this is not a recommended procedure. Please follow the example given with installation is part of building process